# Steps to use juju to orchestrate a devStack fresh VM setup?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualization, virtualbox, openstack, juju

Using this devStack guide : [Running a Cloud in a VM](http://devstack.org/guides/single-vm.html) to test OpenStack.

What would be the steps to get the correct juju configuration from a fresh devStack setup?

**EDIT** : Found out the first configuration parameters but I still did not succeed in making `juju boostrap` work, check my answer below.

---

Looking at this [Ask Ubuntu Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94150/how-do-i-use-openstack-and-keystone-with-juju) :

> You just need to explicitly set the right keys in environments.yaml, specifically ec2-uri, s3-uri, access-key, default-image-id and secret-key.
>
> Your keystone bits should be producing the access key ID and secret key that will be used to populate those fields.

So does anyone knows *how do you get keystone to provide you the access and secret key?* And what would be the ec2-uri, s3-uri?

Comment: I like this question a lot, but I think it has loads of divergent paths to goals, so it's not really a QA style thing.  There is a serious lack of blog articles on automating deployment of VMs in openstack with and without virtualized networking though.  I'll try to remedy that, at least for my deployment of devstack, in the nearish future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like it was quite easy to find theses from the dashboard interface :

http://my.private.cloud/settings/project/ will give you OpenStack API endpoints :

```
ec2-uri: http://my.private.cloud:8773/services/Cloud
s3-uri: http://my.private.s3:3333
```

http://my.private.cloud/settings/ec2/ will enable you to download a  zip file with all the information inside.

```
access-key: random-uuid-follows-1fc1f05e-1c37-4594-8e5e:me_project
secret-key: random-uuid-follows-4a75192b-2478-4acf-a6e8-aa60bbaf1e28
```

---

I'm currently stuck on :

```
user@ubuntu:~$ juju bootstrap --environment openstack
2012-07-16 19:39:32,499 WARNING ssl-hostname-verification is disabled for this environment
2012-07-16 19:39:32,500 WARNING EC2 API calls not using secure transport
2012-07-16 19:39:32,500 WARNING S3 API calls not using secure transport
2012-07-16 19:39:32,500 WARNING Ubuntu Cloud Image lookups encrypted but not authenticated
2012-07-16 19:39:32,503 INFO Bootstrapping environment 'openstack' (origin: distro type: ec2)...
User timeout caused connection failure.
2012-07-16 19:40:02,538 ERROR User timeout caused connection failure.
```